# Using MongoCollection.FindAll returns the same document twice

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

We've run into a bug in our system caused by getting duplicate documents from MongoDB.
This happens when using `FindAll` while updating the collection from another process at the same time.

What is the best practice to avoid this?

We don't mind getting a stale version of the just-updated document, getting just-deleted documents, nor missing just-inserted documents.

We've seen that there is a `SetSnapshot` option for cursors ([`$snapshot: true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/snapshot/)), but what are the performance implications? Why isn't it on by default?

<strike>We can remove the returned duplicates manually but that doesn't seem right and would also be a performance hit.</strike>

---

**Update:**

From our understanding, updates that change the document size may move its location in the collection. If this kind of update happens during the `FindAll` operation when the `$snapshot` option is off, the document can be returned twice.

---

**Update 2:**

Removing duplicates manually at the client-side (in memory) is not an option since some documents may be lost (for the same reasons they can appear twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [FAQ entry](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-isolate-cursors-from-intervening-write-operations) for this which basically says that you can prevent duplicate docs appearing in your query by either:

- Using `$snapshot`, but this can't be used with sharded collections or `sort()`
- Sorting your query on a field that doesn't change and has a unique index

So use `$snapshot` if its restrictions don't create problems for you, or sort your results on static, uniquely indexed field like `_id`, using `hint()` if necessary to ensure it's being used.  Do some profiling with `explain()` to test out your options.

`$snapshot` isn't enabled by default because of its restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, we've seen this FAQ, but is it the way to go? Would it cause more seeks than a queryless find? And if that's the case, would it be better to remove the duplicates in memory after the find?

Comment: Yes it's the way to go.  Removing duplicates client-side is likely going to be slower and is definitely messier.

Comment: Removing duplicates client-side is off the table - Some existing documents may not be returned at all. Do you know if the `$snapshot` option would have negative performance effects? Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the last comment.  By client-side I just mean removing the duplicates in memory after the find.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear comment and quick edit. I meant that after some testing, we found out that updated documents may return twice, OR they may not be returned at all.

Comment: Right. See, I told you it was messier. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63423/discussion-between-kaiser-soze-and-johnnyhk).